# Returning the updated value of variable initialized in a method

Tags: java, android

I have three methods. Let's call them Method 1, Method 2 and Method 3.

Each of these methods contain a String variable which is initailized within the method.
Note: These methods are called when a user clicks a Button, so in other words there's a click listener.

Now what I want to do, in the main method is creating a 4th String variable, which is initialized as such:

```
public class Main{

 String Variable4 = variable1 + variable2 + variable3
    System.out.println(Variable4);
}
```

The problem however is, that variable4 is null.
And this is because the variables in the 3 methods are null in the main method.

But they are initialized locally in the methods.

So how would I return the initialized variable in the main method?

Comment: I am not sure about when you are using your click methods, but you can just initialize your variables like < String variable4 = "" > and so on.

Comment: Hi, for the scope of the project I am working on, that wont do unfortunately

Comment: there is another way you can use make an array of string and useing random method u can get the sting of different position

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of your problem. You say main method, but you have no methods shown. Android tag would also mean there is no main method for an app

Comment: I think @mahbshussain means returning value from the methods of ActionListener classes. Correct me if I am wrong :)

Comment: 1) it seems your variable are local, so there is to declaration (one in the method and one for the class) 2), if the buttons are not called, the variable won't be declare, is it acceptable ? 3) Please show the methods and the declaration of those 3 variable. No need of the click listener (just comment on which are linked to buttons)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a variable depending on other variables, use a method instead of a variable.

```
public class Main{
    String[] variables = new String[3]; 

    public String getVariable4() {
        String s = "":
        for (int i = 0: i < variables.length - 1; i++) {
            s += variables[i] +"  ";
        ) 
        s += variables[variables.length - 1]:
        return s;
    } 

    public void onClick(View v) {
        variables[0] ="blah";  // update the array 
        label.setText(getVariable4()); // get the dynamic variable 
    } 
}
```

Comment: On Java 8, I like the new `String.join(CharSequence, CharSequence...)` method, instead of the for loop. `String.join(" ", variables);`

Comment: Question has android tag, and I've not tried to mess with the compatibility settings with that

Comment: Fair enough, didn't notice the tag since this was not specific here (but Java 8 is only supported on N, maybe not fully)

Answer (score -1):

Yours functions have to return a value. And you need to call directly the function

```
public class Main{

 String Variable4 = "";
 Variable4 = Methode1() + Methode2() + Methode3();
    System.out.println(Variable4);
}
```

And for example your **Methode1 :**

```
public String Methode1(){
    String variable = "initialyze";
    return variable;
}
```

Hope that will help you :)

Comment: Question says Methode1(), for example, is called by a GUI click event, so I doubt calling the method directly helps

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't understand that. It is the reason why I thought it was a strange question ^^